# What Command Would I Use To Give Someone A Stone Pickax Thats called Amazing Man and can break leaves?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I Am Building A Map And I Need A Pickax That Is Called Leaf Breaker And Well Can Only Break Leaves, What Do I Do?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: You are getting down votes because your question shows no research.  The answer to this question is easily obtainable with a web search.  Also the title to the question is asking for a pickaxe named Amazing Man and the body of the question is asking for it to be named Leaf Breaker.

Answer (score 2):

For things like this, you can use a give generator.  It makes it easy and does not require command knowledge.  [Here is the generator](http://www.mapmaking.fr/give/) I used for this answer.

I will give two commands.  One without silk touch that will break leaves but not drop them, and one which will break and drop leaves.

Here is the command without silk touch:

```
/give @p minecraft:stone_pickaxe 1 0 {display:{Name:"Leaf Breaker"},CanDestroy:["minecraft:leaves","minecraft:leaves2"]}
```

Here is the command with silk touch:

```
/give @p minecraft:stone_pickaxe 1 0 {display:{Name:"Leaf Breaker"},CanDestroy:["minecraft:leaves","minecraft:leaves2"],ench:[{id:33,lvl:1}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
/give @p minecraft:stone_pickaxe 1 0 {display:{Name:"Leaf Breaker"},CanDestroy:["minecraft:leaves"]}
```